# What does the two vertical bars mean between a set.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

So I'm just getting the grasp of set theory and I have this question.

> Let $|A| = m$ and $|B| = n$. What is the cardinality of the set $A \times B
> $?

I put $\{1,1\}$ as the answer however I wasn't totally sure what the two vertical bars between set $A$ and set $B$ mean. If anyone could clear this up that would be great.

Comment: The vertical bars mean cardinality. I believe the answer is at most m*n, which the specific answer depending on if the sets have any of the same elements or not.

Comment: @AlanWolfe : That's not true; indeed let's take $A=\{1\}$ and $B=\{1,2\}$, then $A\times B$ is of cardinality exactly $2$ despite $1$ is a common element.

Comment: Few basic examples, $A = \{1,2,3\}$, then $\left\vert A \right\vert = 3$. If $A = \{1, 2, \ldots, m \}$, then $\left\vert A \right\vert = m$. For finite set $A$, it only means, how many elements are there in $A$. For $A = \{1, 2\}, B = \{a, b\}$, then $\left\vert A \right\vert = 2 = \left\vert B\right\vert $, and $A \times B = \{(1,a), (2,a), (1, b), (2, b)\}$ and $\left\vert A\times B \right\vert = 4$.

Comment: So why is A × B for |A| = m and |B| = n mn? Shouldn't it be 2 as you can represent it like {m,n}, {n,m} which is equal to 2?

Answer (score 3):

The notation $|A|$ is just a shorthand for "the cardinality of $A$".

Answer (score 3):

I suspect you are interpreting the question to be saying that set $A$ contains a single element $m$ and set $B$ contains a single element $n$.  That would explain where the $1$s in your answer are coming from, at least -- although I'm not sure why you think $\{1,1\}$ is the answer.

But in any case, that is **not** what it means.  $|A|=m$ means that the set $A$ contains $m$ distinct elements.  $|B|=n$ means that the set $B$ contains $n$ distinct elements.  And $A \times B$ means the set of ordered pairs, where the first element of the pair comes from $A$ and the second element of the ordered pair comes from $B$.

The question you need to ask yourself is:  How many different ways can I fill in the blanks in an ordered pair (**_, _**) where the first blank is filled in with an element of $A$ and the second blank is filled in with an element of $B$?

Comment: Okay so if I'm understanding this correctly its should be {m,n}. Which is then 1?

Comment: @SearchingFor As I said in my answer, the answer will be $mn$.

Comment: @SearchingFor why do you think the answer is an ordered pair, and why do you think the answer is 1?

Comment: I thought the answer is how many ordered pairs are there. So the answer would be 1. So the answer isn't how many ordered pairs are there it's just listing the ordered pairs?

Comment: Why do you think there is only one ordered pair?  There are $m$ different ways to fill in the first blank space; there are $n$ different ways to fill in the second blank space.  How many possible ordered pairs are there?

Comment: Try a specific example:  Suppose $A = \{ x,y,z \}$ and $B = \{ u, v \}$.  So $|A|=3$ and $|B|=2$.  Now, *some* of the ordered pairs would be $(x,u) , (x,v), (y,u), \dots $.  How many ordered pairs are there all together?  *That's* what the question is asking you.

Comment: So for the example of @mweiss said it would be 6 ordered pairs? Or do you have to count ordered pairs which are switched. e.g (x,u) and (u,x) would be two different ordered pairs.

Comment: The first element *has to come from* $A$ and the second element *has to come from* $B$.  So in this example $\{ u, x \}$ would not be a member of $A \times B$.

Answer (score 2):

$|A|$ denotes the cardinality of $A$. Then $|A\times B|=|A|\cdot |B|=mn$ (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product#Cardinality)).

Comment: I thought the cardinality of a set was defined as the number of elements contained in the set. So for example the cardinality of Pow({1, 2, 3}) would be 13.

Comment: If $P(A)$ is the power set of $A$, then $|P(A)|=2^{|A|}$, so $|P(\{1,2,3\})|=2^3=8$. You're right that the cardinality of a set is defined as the number of elements in the set. E.g., $|\{1,2,3\}|=3$.

Comment: Oh my mistake I was counting the elements in the sets and not the sets themselves.